# Testing meteor - testing allow / deny with a unit test instead of integration test

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, jasmine, integration-testing, meteor-velocity

I have an application code that restricts documents in the following manner

```js
Docs.allow({
  insert: function(userId, doc){
    return !!userId
  },
  update: function(userId, doc){
    return userId && doc.owner == userId;
  }
})
```

Currently, I can only run an integration test which makes actual http calls. I am not able to stub the components (Meteor current user) outside the system under test (allow / deny rules).

```js
it("should succeed if user is authenticated", function(done) {
    Meteor.loginWithPassword(’shawn@abc.com', ‘hahaha', function(err){
        expect(err).toBe(undefined);
        Doc = Docs.insert({title: 'abc', 
                           category: 'Finance'}, 
                          function(err, id){
                              expect(err).toBeUndefined();
                              expect(id).not.toBeUndefined();
                              done();
                          });
    });
});

it("should fail if user is not authenticated", function(done) {
    Meteor.logout(function(){
        doc = Docs.insert({title: 'abc', 
                           category: 'Finance', 
                           owner: '1232131'}, 
                          function(err, id){
                              expect(err).not.toBeUndefined();
                              done();
                          });
    });
});
```

This makes my test incredibly slow, especially if there are many paths I want to test. Is there a way for me to move this test to a lower level unit test instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building up on The Meteor Test Manual's answer... `Stories.allow` mock was defined AFTER the app code has loaded. Therefore, it has no effect.

As documented in https://github.com/Sanjo/meteor-jasmine#stubs,

> Files in tests/jasmine folder (or a subfolder of it) that end with -stubs.js or -stub.js are treated as stubs and are loaded before the app code.

So to make The Meteor Test Manual's answer work, we have to define the stub / mock in a -stubs.js file. This is what I've done on `z-security-stubs.js`.

Note I prefixed the file name with 'z' because meteor load files in the same level of a subdirectory in alphabetical order. We have to ensure that our self-defined stubs load after the automatically generated `package-stubs.js` and `packageMocksSpec.js` made by Velocity.

With that in mind, `z-security-stubs.js` can contain something like this:

```
Mongo.Collection.prototype.allow = function(rules){
  this._velocityAllow = rules;
}

Mongo.Collection.prototype.deny = function(rules){
  this._velocityDeny = rules;
}
```

This retains a reference to our allow / deny security rules in a property of a collection instance (eg. Docs, Files, or whatever your collection is named);

Afterwards, we can refer to the security functions in this property and make assertions:

```
describe("Docs security rules", function() {
  var allow;

  beforeEach(function(){
    allow = Docs._velocityAllow;
  });

  it("insert deny access to non-logged in users", function() {
    var response = allow.insert(null, {});
    expect(response).toBe(false);
  });

  it("insert allow access to logged in users", function() {
    var response = allow.insert(true, {});
    expect(response).toBe(true);
  });

  it("update allow access to logged in users who are owners", function() {
    var response = allow.insert(2, {owner: 2});
    expect(response).toBe(true);
  });

  it("update deny access to non-logged in users", function() {
    var response = allow.update(null, {owner: 2});
    expect(response).toBe(false);
  });

  it("update deny access to logged in users who are not owners", function() {
    var response = allow.update(1, {owner: 2});
    expect(response).toBe(false);
  });
});
```

Comment: That's great! I had the exact same solution done locally and wanted to change Jasmine not to force you to use z-xxxx.js for the stub.

Comment: yeah but though if we have multiple .allow inserts / update chains then the above won't work so well since the above assume that there is only one _.velocityAllow.insert

Comment: You can only have one insert/update per collection. So using `Docs._velocityAllow.insert` is fine here, and when you have another collection, you use `AnotherCollection._velocityAllow.insert`

Comment: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/allow `You can call allow as many times as you like, and each call can include any combination of insert, update, and remove functions. The functions should return true if they think the operation should be allowed. Otherwise they should return false, or nothing at all (undefined). In that case Meteor will continue searching through any other allow rules on the collection.`

Answer (score 0):

This test exercises the execution paths on the server code, which is where the allow/deny rules live.

The test here does not exercise the integration between the client the server, that's what your client integration test was doing quite well.

You can use the unit test to cover all the execution paths in the code, and then have less integration tests therefore you'll gain the speed you want.

You should much as much as possible into the lower levels, but not everything. You still want to make sure the integration also works.

```js
describe('Doc security rules', function () {

  var _oldAllowRules;

  beforeAll(function () {
    var _allowRules = null;

    // keep hold of the old Docs.allow method so we can restore in the after step
    _oldAllowRules = Docs.allow;

    // override the Docs.allow method so we can isolate the allow rules code
    Docs.allow = function (allowRules) {
      _allowRules = allowRules;
    };
  });

  afterAll(function () {
    // restore the Docs.allow method 
    Docs.allow = _oldAllowRules;
  });

  it('insert deny access to non-logged in users', function () {
    // Execute
    // you can now exercise the allowRules directly 
    var response = _allowRules.insert(null, {});

    // Verify
    expect(response).toBe(false);
  });

  it('update allows for doc owner', function () {
    // you can do it all with one step
    expect(_allowRules.update(1234, {owner: 1234})).toBe(true);
  });

  it('update denies for logged out user', function () {
    expect(_allowRules.update(null, {})).toBe(false);
  });

  it('update denies for non document owner', function () {
    expect(_allowRules.update(1234, {owner: 5678})).toBe(false);
  });

});
```

Comment: How come this test is included inside 'server' tests? I thought that .allow rules are only exercised when performing client inserts? Server inserts will bypass the allow rules altogether. :(

Comment: just tested it.  `Cannot call method 'insert' of null`. I think the `Docs.allow` overriding code never actually got called.

Comment: I think Jasmine requires beforeAll - I just updated the answer

Comment: I used beforeAll. It didn't work for me. Maybe there's some typo I'm missing but it seems like my app code is loaded before the test code. So that means that '.allow' mock over there didn't get called at all

Comment: I'm going to try to get this working locally and update here.

Comment: I've made an update in another answer that makes use of a stub so that your principle works. Not sure if its the right way.